# Set seeds IP in cassandra.yaml file with a command/script

Tags: cassandra, amazon-ec2

I'm using AWS CloudFormation to create a 3-node Datastax Cassandra cluster. In my ec2-user home directory on all my nodes, I'm creating the seed IP in a text file(seeds.txt).The cluster is being created as expected. Node1 is the seed node. But Node2 and Node3 are setting their respective private IP's as the seed IP. Does anyone know of a script/command to set the seed IP in my cassandra.yaml file on node2 and node3?
I have tried sed command to cat seeds.txt from ec2-user home directory and modify the cassandra.yaml file, but it doesn't work. Here's a portion of my cassandra.yaml file,

```
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points.
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "1.2.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

we have a similar setup and used etcd and the [etcd-seed provider](https://github.com/zalando/cassandra-etcd-seed-provider) in order to figure out our seed nodes.

This implies that you have to register your seed node during startup in the etcd cluster. We solved this by adjusting the startup-script of cassandra.

See (line 62):
https://github.com/zalando/stups-cassandra/blob/master/stups-cassandra.sh

Best Regards,

Malte

Answer (score 0):

You can look at what 
https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI is doing for DS Cassandra AMI.
In short, they are using a centralized reflector service, to which all nodes connects over HTTP.